# Or and AND statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

So i'm trying to enable a textbox whenever the user selects "female" as her gender and "married, widow" as her civil status, and it will just be disabled for those who will select "male" for their status. but it's not working with the code i have. please help me, i'm not good in javascript. thank you

php file

```
$maiden = $gender = $status = "";

$maidenErr = $genderErr = $statusErr = "";

?>
```

Validation of the textboxes.

```
//Maiden
    if(empty($_POST["maiden"])) {  
     $maidenErr = "Missing maiden name";  
     $valid =false;  
      }  
   else {  
      $maiden = test_input($_POST["maiden"]);  
           // check if name only contains letters and whitespace  
   if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$MI))  
    {  
     $maidenErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";  
    $valid=false;  
       }  
   }
//gender   
   if (isset($_POST["gender"])) {  
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]); 

      }  
   else {  
      $genderErr = "specify your gender";  
     $valid=false;
   }  
//status
    if (empty($_POST["status"])) {  
     $statusErr = "specify your status";  
     $valid=false;  
      }  
   else {  
     $status = test_input($_POST["status"]);  
   }
```

and this is my javascript where i want the enabling and disabling of the button to happen.

```
<script>

    function enable_text(status)
    {
    status=!status; 
        document.f1.other_text.disabled = status;
    }
    function makeDisable(){
        var x=document.getElementById("mySelect")
        x.disabled=true
    }
    function makeEnable(){
        var x=document.getElementById("mySelect")
        if((document.getElementById("status").value =="single") && (document.getElementById("gender").value =="female"))
        {
            x.disabled=true
        }
        else
        {
            x.disabled=false
        }
    }

    });

    </script>
```

this is my html page.

```
<form>

 <label for="maidenname" >Maiden Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="maiden" id="mySelect" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($maiden);?>" disabled=true maxlength="20" placeholder="Maidenname">
            <p><span class="message">(for female only)</span></p>
            <span class="error"><?php echo $maidenErr;?></span>  
        </div>

        <label for="gender" >Gender&nbsp;</label><br />
            <input type=radio name="gender" value="<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="male")echo "checked";?>" id="gender" onclick="makeDisable()">Male &nbsp;
            <input type=radio name="gender" value="<?php if (isset($gender) && $gender=="female")echo "checked";?>" id="gender" onclick="makeEnable()" >Female 
            <p><span class="error"><?php echo $genderErr;?></span></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
        <label for="atatus" >Civil Status</label>
            <select name="status" id="status" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($status);?>"  onChange="makeEnable()">
                <option value="single">Single</option>
                <option value="married">Married</option>
                <option value="widow/er">Widow/er</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
                </select>
                <p><span class="error"><?php echo $statusErr;?></span></p>
        </div>


</form>
```

Comment: where is your problem and what would you like help with?

Comment: My problem is my AND OR statement in javascript won't work. @AdamBuchananSmith

Comment: can you provide your html?

Comment: and put `;` after `var x=document.getElementById("mySelect")`

Comment: and try changing this `.value =="single"` to this `.value ==="single"`

Comment: Show the relevant html and also create a demo that replicates problem. We have no idea how these methods are used

Comment: Try to alert(document.getElementById("status").value) and see if your getting what you expect. I dont see how you trigger the event but are you using the onchange event to run your javascript function?

Comment: hi, i used onchange event. i posted my html page above. thank u for helping @MadeInDreams

Comment: i posted my html page above. thank u for helping @charlietfl

Comment: The core problem is that you have the same id on both radio buttons, which is not allowed. `getElementById` only targets one of them.

Answer (score 1):

I made a jQuery solution, since it's tagged in your post. To incorporate this in your page, you would need to make sure to include jQuery (I used version 1.12.0). I removed the PHP stuff, since you're asking about the JavaScript, and I removed the onclick/onchange attributes, so I could set up the click listeners in jQuery instead.

Here's the applicable jQuery:

```
$(document).on("change", "[name=gender],[name=status]", function(){
  var gender = $('[name=gender]:checked').val();
  var status = $('[name=status] option:selected').val();
  if(gender == 'female' && status == 'single'){
    $('[name=maiden]').prop('disabled', false);
  }
  else{
    $('[name=maiden]').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

I did have to modify one other thing in your HTML too - I added values for the male and female gender checkboxes (the values being "male" and "female"). Here's the minimal HTML I tested with:

```
<form>
  <label for="maidenname" >Maiden Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="maiden" id="mySelect" value="" disabled=true maxlength="20" placeholder="Maidenname">
  <p><span class="message">(for female only)</span></p>
  <span class="error"></span>  

  <label for="gender" >Gender&nbsp;</label><br />
  <input type=radio name="gender" id="gender" value='male'>Male &nbsp;
  <input type=radio name="gender" id="gender" value='female'>Female 
  <p><span class="error"></span></p>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="atatus" >Civil Status</label>
    <select name="status" id="status">
      <option value="single">Single</option>
      <option value="married">Married</option>
      <option value="widow/er">Widow/er</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <p><span class="error"></span></p>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here's a fiddle for you to review it working with comments: https://jsfiddle.net/fo8m8fta/

Comment: thank you, that actually helped, i just edited it with how i wanted it. thanks!!! :)

Comment: No problem. LOL at my mistake though - if single and female, enter maiden name... like that makes sense! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I tried mark.hch's code and I finally did it the way I wanted it. So here's my final code that's from mark.hch :)

**Javascript**

```
<script>
    //whenever an item with the name attribute set to gender or status is changed:
    $(document).on("change", "[name=gender],[name=status]", function(){
        //gather the checked gender
        var gender = $('[name=gender]:checked').val();
      //gather the selected status
      var status = $('[name=status] option:selected').val();
      //if the user checked female and selected single
      if(gender == 'female' && status != 'single'){
        //enable the maidenname input
        $('[name=maiden]').prop('disabled', false);
      }
     else{
        //disable the maidenname input
        $('[name=maiden]').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    });
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
  <label for="maidenname" >Maiden Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="maiden" id="mySelect" value="" disabled=true maxlength="20" placeholder="Maidenname">
  <p><span class="message">(for female only)</span></p>
  <span class="error"></span>  

  <label for="gender" >Gender&nbsp;</label><br />
  <input type=radio name="gender" id="gender" value='male'>Male &nbsp;
  <input type=radio name="gender" id="gender" value='female'>Female 
  <p><span class="error"></span></p>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="atatus" >Civil Status</label>
    <select name="status" id="status">
      <option value="single">Single</option>
      <option value="married">Married</option>
      <option value="widow/er">Widow/er</option>
      <option value="other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <p><span class="error"></span></p>
  </div>
</form>
```